# Usage of image in sIFR

Tags: sifr

I want to use sIFR in my blog posts also. But there's a major problem that I couldn't fix.

Let's say the blog post is between these divs:

```
<div class="post">BLOG POST IS HERE</div>
```

So, my selector is .post.

When I insert an image tag inside this div, the image isn't being showed by the browser. Just like this:

```
<div class="post"><img src="myimage.jpg" align="left" />BLOG POST IS HERE</div>
```

Is there a way to use sIFR with images?

Comment: This is a bad idea. Please restrict sIFR usage to small amounts of text. It's meant just for headers, etc., not whole blog posts.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know sIFR is not capable of displaying images. It is not intended to change an entire blog post. You should concentrate on the headlines.

Answer (score 0):

i would recommend you place your blog post paragraphs inside `<p>` tags and then sIFR `.post p` in your css if you're going to do it, but as said above sIFR on a large amount of text is a bad idea...

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend reforming your markup so that the headline is in some sort of header element. like so...

```
<div class="post"><img src="myimage.jpg" align="left" /><h2>BLOG POST IS HERE</h2></div>
```

Then you could select on .post h2 in your sIFR declaration. This should achieve the effect you're looking for, and be much better for SEO.

Answer (score -1):

Not really meant to be used for huge blocks of text. It's a fairly elegant solution for problems, but it's still flash, so don't go mental because you'll begin to degrade the user's experience, and that's counter to what you're after.